# How to get the second last partition in hive (HQL)

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have a hive table with below partitions:

`part_date='07-12-2016'`

`part_date='04-12-2016'`

`part_date='01-12-2016'`

Now how can I get the first partition which is less than the most recent partition in hive query. Assuming the partition values are the date when the data is ingested into the table. 
In this case it should be part_date='04-12-2016'.

so the query should be like:

`select part_date  from table_A where part_date > second_last_partition(ie 04-12-2016);`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `row_number` window function and get the second latest row.

```
select part_date
from (select part_date,row_number() over(order by part_date desc) as rn 
      from table_A) t
where rn = 2
```

I assume the `part_date` column is distinct. If not, you should use the `dense_rank` function.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer but I am trying to get the second last partition value, not the entire data in the partition. I can edit the question.

Comment: Thanks this works. But for a zero byte file in hdfs, I am unable to get the query wok. Since hive reads the 0 byte file and finds no value for the partition.Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: unfortunately i don't know the answer to that.

Comment: So you have added partitions but don't have data for that partition and want to get the partition(which is 2nd last)?

Comment: yeah correct  . Seems like it cannot be achieved using hive